# for a one-dimensional string array that converts every 2 bits from binary to decimal For example: str [] = {"10 1111 1010" } => 2 33 22

Tags: binary

for a one-dimensional string array that converts every 2 bits from binary to decimal

For example: str [] = {"10 1111 1010"  } => 2 33 22
str[]={"" 11 01 1010"}=>3 1 22[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bupqx.png)

Comment: `perl -pe 's/[01]{2}/oct("0b$&")/eg'`

Comment: Please don't add images as links , you can upload the images in  StackOverFlow itself. Thank you.